# where does the idiom 'driving me mad' come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms

any ideas? It's for use in an English Language class I teach.

Comment: I don't suppose it's anywhere near the *first* citation, but here's one from 1836: ["You are driving me mad, father!"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22driving+me+mad+father%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I don't see how anyone can meaningfully answer "Where did this usage come from?" - it's just basic English, used as it has been for centuries.

Comment: ...also [Will you drive me mad, Julia!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22driving+me+mad+father%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22you+drive+me+mad+julia%22&tbm=bks) from 1790.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Always include the question in the body, not just the title. Make sure the sentences are grammatically correct with proper punctuation, capitalization, etc. After all, this is English Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

Among it's meanings, *drive* has always also had the meaning of *forcing, pushing* (the cattle, for example, or even some abstract thing).

Regarding the contruction itself, in which the action results in the object becoming changed in some way, it's called *adjectival resultative*. It is typical of Germanic languages (as opposed to Romance languages) and English features it abundantly. *She beat him black-and-blue. They robbed us poor. I shot him dead.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's *driving* in the sense of pushing toward and *mad* as a synonym for crazy or insane.

That's really all it is.

> Your incessant tapping is driving me insane/crazy/nuts/mad!

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I think you're probably right but disappointed there isn't more to it. In this sense, it's a metaphor probably, since idioms tend to have a good story behind them.

Comment: It's a metaphor in any sense. Most idioms come from metaphors. And there's no such thing as **just** a metaphor; metaphors are all there is.

Comment: @user52882 like many idioms such as this, it's just hyperbole. That's really it.

Answer (score 1):

*Drove her mad* can be found at least as early as 1728 in *[Augusta Triumphans: Or, The Way to Make London the Most Flourishing City in the Universe](http://books.google.com/books?id=RnZbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA36&dq=%22drives%20her%20mad%22%20OR%20%22driving%20her%20mad%22%20OR%20%22driven%20her%20mad%22%20OR%20%22drove%20her%20mad%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t5NEUsH1Ioqv4ASfrID4DQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ)* by Daniel Defoe:

> [image: During her Confinement, the Villain of the Mad-Houfe frequently attempted her Chaftity ; and the more fhe repuls'd him, the worfe he treated her : till at laft he drove - her mad in good earneft. Her diftreffed Brother, who is fond of her to -the laft ...]

And *drives me mad* from 1730 in Thomas Walker's play, [*The fate of villany: A play. As it is acted by the company of comedians, at the Theatre in Goodmans-Fields*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tdZUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22drives%20me%20mad%22%20OR%20%22driving%20me%20mad%22%20OR%20%22driven%20me%20mad%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=So9EUtGeD-ja4ATSl4HICw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA):

> [image: Recal him, fetch him back. Sebastians Attend the Summons of the fair Fittoria. Now judge the Force of Love, thou frozen Parents See me resign the Treasure of my Soul 5 A Task, which, but to think on, drives me mad, And hurls me to Despair.]